# Icon for "Add to Homescreen" fails, always the normal icon for favoriten appears

Tags: google-chrome, icons, addition, homescreen

I've tried for hours to get the icon from the Chrome function "add to homescreen"  (Zum Startbildschirm hinzufügen) but it appears only the icon for the normal favorits.

I use an IIS as webserver, and write the html exakt as in the Chrome Doku.

```
<title>MangoApp</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="icon" sizes="196x196" href="http://tatwebapp196x196.png">
```

I've tried with different paths like relative and absolut but always the same effect: no icon.
Tested on Nexus and Xcover2 with the newest Chrome browser Versions 36.0.1985.128 and 35.0 1916.141

What is wrong here, can anybody help ?

Thank you 
Michaela

Comment: I think Chrome broke something in one of their latest builds.  I got this to work back in June with a production website that I have, but now when I try to add it again to my homescreen, it fails.  Have you found an answer to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet (I should use this more!)...

I've tested, with an application I'm currently developing, on:

- Nexus 10 (Chrome 36.) ~ favicon used
- SG SV (Chrome 36.) ~ favicon used
- SG SV (Chrome Beta 37.) ~ favicon used

and finally...

- SG SIII (Chrome 35.0.1916.141 (for some reason)) ~ 196x196 icon used! (this is the same as a version you tested this on, though, so for reference, it's running 4.3 still)

I guess this should provide some more validity to Michael's point, so I guess I'll file a bug report and hope for an update soon.  Regardless, I'm strangely glad to see there's actually a problem.

A link to my app, which is actually a game (the most stable thing should be the icons...) [here](http://students.challoners.com/ts/game).

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know if this is working in Chrome 37 now.

We are using the same meta tags with a slightly different format for the icon, adding the "type" attribute, that may matter. This works in Android 4.0+ with Chrome 37, as well as iOS.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="images/AppIcon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/AppIcon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://ourURL/images/iPhoneStartup.png">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, height=device-height, width=device-width" />
```